# What is magnetization resistance and how to calculate(or measure, or estimate) it?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductance

What is magnetization resistance? How to calculate or measure or estimate it?

Edit: I'm trying to build a smps simulation on simulink, in transformer block I have a parameter named magnetization resistance and I don't know what to write here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Context please?

Comment: In modelling a transformer there's usually a resistor put in parallel with the magnetizing inductance that represents the core losses.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @Andyaka editted

Comment: @JohnD probably this is it, and I need to find it's value.

Comment: Transformers don't have magnetization resistance hence, more context needed.

Comment: @Andyaka I added a picture to question, on the bottom block is asking for a magnetization resistance parameter. I don't know what to write here if there is no magnetization resistance.

Comment: You'll need to dig a bit deeper into your tool to find out if it's representing core loss resistance. There should be a transformer equivalent circuit that shows where the parameter is in the model.

Comment: It is to model core losses and it can be ignored as a first approximation - set it to a very high value, a few megs and it should do for a first round.

Comment: @Andyaka I added the equivalent circuit from help documentation, it also say that it simulates the core losses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetizing resistance is the Rm and is used to model the no-load losses in the classic equivalent circuit of the transformer. To calculate you need to know the no-load losses and the voltage of the primary (there is a detail on which side to position the magnetizing branch, in your figure, it is in the primary winding, numbered as 1). You can use:
$$Rm=V_1^2/P_0$$.